# How can I make a line break when writing a string to a file?

Tags: java, string, file, line-breaks

I want to write text into a file and everytime I do it should make a new line. I've seen many answers to this question being just "use \n" but that doesn't work for me.

This is the code I used:

```
File file = new File("C:\\Users\\Schule\\IdeaProjects\\projectX\\src\\experiment\\input.txt");
        boolean result;
        if(!file.exists()) {
            try {
                // create a new file
                result = file.createNewFile();
                // test if successfully created a new file
                if(result) {
                    System.out.println("Successfully created " + file.getCanonicalPath());
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        String output = name + ": " + highscoreString + "\n";
        try {
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(file, true));
            out.append(output);
            out.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

The code I have writes the new Highscore and the name of the person who made it in a file. It works perfectly fine except that it writes everything on a line like this for example:
Nicola: Your highscore is 10 secondsThomas: Your highscore is 11 seconds
But I want:
Nicola: Your highscore is 10 seconds
Thomas: Your highscore is 11 seconds

I know there are some other things I need to fix and improve but right now, this is my biggest problem. Does anyone know what to do?
(sorry for my name btw ;)

Comment: `\n` is a Unix style line ending. Windows style is `\r\n`. Almost any editor accepts both formats, but my guess is you're viewing your file in Notepad :)

Comment: Documentation of `PrintWriter` should help: [println](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/io/PrintWriter.html#println()) (instead of `append()`)- Which you are already using like in `System.out.println(...)` - so no need to *know* which OS this is running on neither use `"\n"`

Comment: The `exists()/createNewFile()`code here is a complete waste of time and space. `new FileWriter()` already does all that. You are forcing it to happen twice.

Comment: it's plain java, looks unrelated to fx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Windows and Linux line breaks are different. Try to write `\r\n`.

**EDIT**

If you use `System.lineSeparator()` to get line break it will give platform based line break. So if you create a file on unix and send it to windows users they will see that file like one line. But if you are using windows os to create file, linux users will see file correct.

Comment: the OP should use the higher level api provided by the PrintWriter - that will take care of OS differences (vs. going so low-level): the general rule is to use the highest semantic abstraction that's available

Comment: Yes you are right for writing the file but my opinion is about reading the file( with OS differences )

Comment: you do the inverse with LineNumberReader - again system specifcs are hidden :)

Answer (score 6):

You need to do: `out.write(System.getProperty("line.separator"));`

`System.getProperty("line.separator")` will give you the line separator for your platform (whether Windows/Linux/..).

Comment: `System.lineSeparator()` is simpler and returns the same

Comment: using `println` is even simpler (since OP already has a `PrintWriter`)

Comment: Be carefull to use `System.lineSeparator()` or `System.getProperty("line.separator")` windows do not see linux line breaks !

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger is on spot - using the highest semantic abstraction available (that fulfills the requirement) is always the route to take